# why Buick Park Avenue blowing hot air on drivers side?

Tags: ac, buick, park-avenue

Just had new battery installed, now a/c on drivers side warm while passenger side nice and cool. Why?

Comment: Was it blowing cold before the battery was changed? Have you moved the selector to another position (like the floor or defrost) and back again? What year Park Avenue is this?

Comment: Please provide the specific model and model year.

Answer (score 2):

Could have freaked out the HVAC actuators . You could try to have the actuators re-homed at a dealership or any shop that has a Tech 2 scanner on hand . If this dose not fix the issue look for codes in the HVAC module you could have a bad temp door actuator .

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind, the blend door motor seized while trying to home (not that uncommon an occurrence after disconnecting the battery or if it dies) or you need to home the controller/motor. The homing /calibration is as follows:
•set the temp controls to a little over 1/2 
•set the fan on medium (3)
•turn the ignition off 
•remove the HVAC fuse or disconnect the battery for 1 minute 
•remove the HVAC fuse or disconnect the battery for 1 minute 
•install the fuse or reconnect the battery
•start the engine
•let it idle for 2 minutes
•turn off the ignition for at least 10 seconds but no more than 30 
•restart the engine and test the a/c controls